# Thymeleaf cannot resolve static ressources when using SpringMVC's @PathVariable

Tags: html, css, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

somehow my CSS-file is not included into my thymeleaf-template.

First of all I need to explain the workflow:

1. User clicks on form-Submit to send a POST to /historyDetails/{history_id}
2. Some  data will be fetched from database using the history_id
3. The data will be rendered on history-detail-view.html

This is my DispatcherServlet:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("*")
public class DispatcherServlet extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        /*
         * resolve path to static ressources (images, stylesheets, javascript-files)
         */
        registry.addResourceHandler("img/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/static/img/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("css/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/static/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("js/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/static/js/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver vr = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

        vr.setTemplateEngine(getTemplateEngine());

        return vr;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine getTemplateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine te = new SpringTemplateEngine();

        te.setTemplateResolver(getTemplateResolver());
        te.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);

        return te;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver getTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver tr = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();

        tr.setApplicationContext(ctx);
        tr.setOrder(1);
        /*
         * resolve path to html to WEB-INF/<name>.html
         * 
         * name can be something like templates/xxx.html
         */
        tr.setPrefix("WEB-INF/");
        tr.setSuffix(".html");

        return tr;
    }
}
```

My projectstructure (from root-directory):

[image]

This is the htistory-detail-view.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet"
                type="text/css"
                th:href="@{css/style.css}"/>

        <script type="text/javascript"
                th:src="@{https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                th:src="@{js/utilities.js}"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div th:replace="fragments/grid :: grid(${grid}, 'HISTORY_DETAIL')"></div>
        <div th:replace="fragments/paging :: paging(${grid})"></div>
    </body>

    <div th:replace="fragments/general :: footer"></div>
</html>
```

While the index.html is rendered with css, the history-detail-view.html is not but rather plain html.

The only errormessage, which I took from the network-tab in firefox is:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:9080/MyProject/historyDetails/js/utilities.js”.
```

The reason why I put the DispatcherServlet into this thread is becouse it is responsible for resolving the paths to the static ressources. When comparing the path from the projectstructure with the path in the errormessage, the DispatcherServlet doesn't seem to work properly but I don't know how to make it resolve the correct path.

The only difference I see here is the Pathvariable.

**EDIT:** I'm providing my index.html, since it is working properly here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet"
                type="text/css"
                th:href="@{css/style.css}"/>

        <script type="text/javascript"
                th:src="@{https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
                th:src="@{js/utilities.js}"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div th:replace="fragments/grid :: grid(${grid}, 'HISTORY')"></div>
        <div th:replace="fragments/paging :: paging(${grid})"></div>
    </body>

    <div th:replace="fragments/general :: footer"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: Does using `"@{/js/utilities.js}` instead of `"@{js/utilities.js}` work?

Comment: no unfortunatly not, also in my DispatcherServlet the / at the beginning is resolved anyway (in my index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because of the spring security configuration if any. Add the path to your CSS static files as an exception in the spring security configuration.

If you are not using spring security or that you have provided the exception, make sure you have followed the standard folder structure.

Go through [this link](https://memorynotfound.com/adding-static-resources-css-javascript-images-thymeleaf/) for more details.

Comment: 1. i didnt mention anything about spring security, therefore im not using it
2. i screenshoted the project structure, which is not the default but thats why i provided my DispatcherServlet
3. as i mentioned in index.html my static ressources are resolvable but in my history-detail-view.html not, since i dont see any differences between them both (<head>-section is the same) i cannot explain why it cannot resolve the static ressources
4. nowhere did i mention this is a springboot project, its a JEE project therefore i need to map the links to my static ressources in the dispatcher servlet